# How can i split adjacent numbers and letters in c++?

Tags: c++, parsing, split, char

I've got a large text document that including adjacent numbers and letters.
Just like that,
JACK1940383DAVID30284HAROLD68372TROY4392 etc.

How can i split this like below in C++

List: Jack / 1940383 , David/30284, ...

Comment: Probably something with a [`regex_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator)

Comment: Going from number to string is relatively easy, but the reverse... not so much I'd read through the string character by character and separate when the result of calls to `isdigit` change state.

Comment: You could *find the first* character that is not alpha (letter), then make a substring. The next substring would be terminated by the first character that is not a digit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::string::find_first_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) and [`std::string::find_first_not_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) in a loop, using [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract each piece, eg:

```cpp
std::string s = "JACK1940383DAVID30284HAROLD68372TROY4392";
std::string::size_type start = 0, end;

while ((end = s.find_first_of("0123456789", start)) != std::string::npos) {
    std::string name = s.substr(start, end-start);
    start = end;

    int number;
    if ((end = s.find_first_not_of("0123456789", start)) != std::string::npos) {
        number = std::stoi(s.substr(start, end-start));
    }
    else {
        number = std::stoi(s.substr(start));
    }
    start = end;

    // use name and number as needed...
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/RJ5cxQ)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

// create a struct to group your data
// this makes it easy to store it in a vector.
struct person_t
{
    std::string name;
    std::string number;
};


// overloaded output operator for printing one person's details
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const person_t& person)
{
    std::cout << person.name << ": " << person.number << std::endl;
    return os;
}

// get a vector of person_t based on the input
auto get_persons(const std::string& input)
{
    // make a regex in this case a regex that will match one or more capital letters 
    // and groups them using the ()
    // then match one or more digits and group them too.
    static const std::regex rx{ "([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)" };
    std::smatch match;

    // a vector to hold all the persons
    std::vector<person_t> persons;

    // start at begin of string and look for first part of the string
    // that matches the regex.
    auto cbegin = input.cbegin();

    while (std::regex_search(cbegin, input.cend(), match, rx))
    {
        // match[0] will contain the whole match, 
        // match[1]-match[n] will contain the groups from the regular expressions
        // match[1] will contain the match with characters and thus the name
        // match[2] will contain the match with the numbers and thus the number.
        // create a person_t struct with this info
        person_t person{ match[1], match[2] };

        // and add it to the vector
        persons.push_back(person);
        cbegin = match.suffix().first;
    }

    return persons;
}

int main()
{
    // parse and split the string
    auto persons = get_persons("JACK1940383DAVID30284HAROLD68372TROY4392");

    // show the output
    for (const auto& person : persons)
    {
        std::cout << person;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok lemme add some comments ;)

Comment: Also, [prefer `'\n'` over `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n). The latter is equivalent to the former, but forces a flush of the output, which is usually not needed and might hurt performance.

Comment: @UnholySheep I make regex static because of the runtime regex compilation overhead. But not needed for the match. So fixed it

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in other good answers you can use

- `find_first_of()`, `find_first_not_of()` and `substr()` from `std::string` in a loop
- `regex`

> But it may be too much. I will add 3 more examples that you may find
> simpler.

The first 2 programs expects the file name on the command line for (my) convenience here, and the test file is `in.txt`. Contents are the same as posted

```
JACK1940383DAVID30284HAROLD68372TROY4392
```

The last example just parses the string data declared as a `char[]`

#### 1. Using `fscanf()`

Since the target is to consume formatted data, `fscanf()` is an option. As the data structure is very simple, the program is just a one line loop:

```
    char  mask[] = "%50[^0-9]%50[0-9]";
    while ( 2 == fscanf(F, mask, tk_key, tk_value))
        std::cout << tk_key << "/" << tk_value << "\n";
```

#### program output

**output is the same for all examples**

```
JACK/1940383
DAVID/30284
HAROLD/68372
TROY/4392
```

#### code for ex. 1

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {   std::cerr << "Use: pgm FileName\n";
        return -1;
    }
    FILE* F = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (F == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not open file");
        return -1;
    }
    std::cerr << "File: \"" << argv[1] << "\"\n";
    char  tk_key[50], tk_value[50];
    char  mask[] = "%50[^0-9]%50[0-9]";
    while ( 2 == fscanf(F, mask, tk_key, tk_value))
        std::cout << tk_key << "/" << tk_value << "\n";
    fclose(F);
    return 0;
}
```

#### using a state machine

There are just 2 states so it is not a fancy FSA ;) State machines are good for representing this kind of stuff, albeit here this seems to be overkill.

```
#define S_LETTER 0
#define S_DIGIT 1
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
    using iich = std::istream_iterator<char>;

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    std::ifstream in_file{argv[1]};
    if ( not in_file.good()) return -1;
    iich p {in_file}, eofile{};
    std::string token{}; // string to build values
    char        st = S_LETTER; // state value for FSA
    std::for_each(p, eofile,
        [&token,&st](char ch)
        {
            char temp = 0;
            switch (st)
            {
                case S_LETTER:
                    if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9'))
                    {
                        std::cout << token << "/";
                        token = ch;
                        st    = S_DIGIT;  // now in number
                    }
                    else token += ch;  // concat in string
                    break;

                case S_DIGIT:
                default:

                    if ((ch < '0') || (ch > '9'))
                    {  // is a letter
                        std::cout << token << "\n";
                        token = ch;
                        st    = S_LETTER;  // now in name
                    }
                    else token += ch;  // concat in string
                    break;
            };  // switch()
        });
    std::cout << token << "\n";  // print last token
}
```

Here we have no loop. `for_each` gets the data from an iterator and passes it to a function that builds the name and the value as strings and `cout`s them

Output is the same

#### 3. a simple FSA to consume the data

```
#define     S_LETTER 0
#define     S_DIGIT  1
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    char one[] = "JACK1940383DAVID30284HAROLD68372TROY4392";
    char*       p     = (char*)&one;
    char*       token = p;
    char        st    = S_LETTER;
    char        temp  = 0;
    while (*p != 0)
    {
        switch (st)
        {
            case S_LETTER:
                if ((*p >= '0') && (*p <= '9'))
                {
                    temp = *p;
                    *p   = 0;
                    std::cout << token << "/";
                    *p    = temp;
                    token = p;
                    st    = S_DIGIT;  // now in number
                }
                break;

            case S_DIGIT:
            default:
                if ( (*p < '0') || (*p > '9'))
                {   // letter
                    temp = *p;
                    *p   = 0;
                    std::cout << token << "\n";
                    *p    = temp;
                    token = p;
                    st    = S_LETTER;  // now in name
                }
                break;
        };  // switch()
        p += 1; // next symbol
    };  // while()
    std::cout << token << "\n"; // print last token
}
```

This code just uses a C-style loop to parse the input data